# Combining Count and Round

Tags: sql, t-sql, count, rounding

I calculate proportionate holiday by:

```
Count(Distinct Case When Workday NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') 
AND hours > '0' then workday END) * Holidays / 5
```

I want to round every value in that column to nearest half and found that SELECT ROUND(2.2 * 2,0) / 2 is doing the rounding job.

Now i just doesnt get it together. As far as i can see Select Round expression gives me a scalar but i want to get every value in my column be rounded.  Round(expression above, * 2.0) / 2 is not working (underlines everything red).

Comment: Put that expression into a derived table (subquery with an alias), give the result an alias, and round the result.

Comment: Does that top expression even work?  It looks like the parenthesis end in the middle of the `WHEN...THEN` portion of the `CASE`.  Is this some kind of twisted SQL version of Duff's Device?

Comment: you are right, a parenthesis wasnt copied. edit done. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a separate Update?

```
Count(Distinct Case 
When Workday NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') 
AND hours > '0' 
then workday 
END) * Holidays / 5 as RoundThis

Update TableName
Set RoundThis = Round(RoundThis * 2.0) / 2
```

Or use variables

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got an expression that compiles, this should do the trick:

`ROUND( 2 * CAST(/*equation*/ AS DECIMAL), 0) / 2;`

Note: You should probably cast to decimal **before** dividing by 5 however.

**EDIT:** Spelling out what works on my system:

```
ROUND(2 * (
  CAST(
    COUNT(Distinct Case When Workday NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
    AND hours > '0' then workday END)
  AS DECIMAL) * Holidays / 5
), 0) / 2
```

Is this giving you an error or just the wrong result?

Comment: thanks. unfortunately this is not working, not even when i try the functions (Round and Cast) seperatly on the expression.

Comment: @ruedi Updated answer with the full column formula.